# Where to add image layer for xcode objects?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to add a border around my UIimageView?

Let's say everytime I add a new photo:

```
flagImageView.image = UIImage(named: correctAnswer)
```

the photo is different, and I need to re-scale.

Where do I put the code, although its not the right answer. I am unsure how to rescale the imageview

```
// Define a new image object
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"lake.png"];

// Define a new image view
UIImageView* imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 157, 125)];

// Set image in imageview and add to view
[imgView setImage:image];
[[self view] addSubview:imgView];

// Create a white border with defined width
imgView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
imgView.layer.borderWidth = 1.5;

// Set image corner radius
imgView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;

// To enable corners to be "clipped"
[imgView setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

I have a code that adds a new image, with different size to a UIimageView. How would I add an image? Is that in a subclass, or viewController, or model?

Comment: I am not sure I understood the question. btw you may want to start using swift (especially if you are learning now) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

this would be the code in swift:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Define a new image object
    let image = UIImage(named: "massage.jpg")
    // Define a new image view
    let  imgView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 40, width: 157, height: 125))
    // Set image in imageview and add to view
    imgView.image = image
    self.view.addSubview(imgView)
    // Create a white border with defined width
    imgView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    imgView.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
    imgView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
    imgView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

this is how it would look like:

[image]
`viewDidLoad` is called when the controller loads it's view, which is not necessarily right after initialisation.

`viewWillAppear` is called just before the view is displayed.`viewWillAppear` is called every time the view is displayed;